# Changing box background color on MUI Date Picker

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to implement the MUI Date Picker on my training website but it is inheriting the background color from its parent.
Is there a way to change the picker box so I can see it better? Adding a className to the component and adding CSS didn't work.

I tried to add in-line stying with
<BasicDateCalendar sx={{background-color: 'white'}}/>

and also tried to add

with
CSS .startDate { background-color: white }

but neither worked. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.